# Lua где взять функцию-аналог string.lower для кириллицы

Tags: lua, кириллица

Мне нужна функция перевода строки в нижний регистр для кириллицы.
Как я понял - стандартная не работает.
Я использую скрипты Lua в среде LuaLaTeX.
По этой причине мне нужна отдельная функция, а не библиотека.
Приведите, пожалуйста, пример функции перевода в нижний регистр для работы с кириллицей.
Заранее спасибо.

```
print(string.lower("Supervisory Control And Data Acquisition"))
print(string.lower("Ямало-Ненецкий Автономный Округ")) -- не работает!
```

Результат:

```
supervisory control and data acquisition
Ямало-Ненецкий Автономный Округ
```

Comment: написать самому, через проход по строке посимвольно и простую замену заглавных на строчные

Comment: Спасибо. Я тоже так думаю, но я удивлен, что стандартная функция не работает с кириллицей! @Mike V.

Comment: Наоборот, странно было бы, если сработала. Стандартная функция работает с латиницей, т.е. с первыми 127 символами из набора ANSI, которые для любой локали одинаковые, а вот для кириллицы (или других национальных кодировок) выделены символы из второй части ANSI с кодами от 128 до 255, ну и они разные для множества различных кодировок. Поэтому нет универсальной функции. И это только для 1-байтных кодировок, не говоря уже о двухбайтных utf-8 и многобайтных unicode.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы `string.lower` работала с кириллицей, нужно установить русскую локаль вызовом `os.setlocale` с именем локали.
Если у Вас русскоязычная ОС, то достаточно вызвать `os.setlocale("")` с пустым именем локали - подставится дефолтная локаль ОС.

Comment: Я использую скрипт Lua в LuaLaTeX.
Скрипты проверяю вот тут: https://www.jdoodle.com/execute-lua-online/
os.setlocale("")
print(string.lower("Supervisory Control And Data Acquisition"))
print(string.lower("Ямало-Ненецкий Автономный Округ"))
Не работает! Там на удаленной машине нет русскоязычной ОS.
@ESkri

Comment: `os.setlocale` платформозависима, поэтому тестировать нужно на такой же OS с точно такими же языковыми настройками.  Если ОС не русскоязычная, то подставить пустую строку не получится, т.к. дефолтная локаль не русская.  Нужно: 1) установить русскую локаль на ОС; 2) указать имя локали при вызове `os.setlocale()`

Comment: Спасибо, @ESkri.